# How to post any JSON content to azure time series insight through the rest api

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

Context: My job is to measure the performance of an in-premise application using JMeter and want to push the result to Azure time series insight. I am using Gen2 time series insight and below is my payload from JMeter,

```
{
    "id": "24f2b702-b2f6-4918-b969-7ed6f6ddc7c7",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "TestProject"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T01_Launch_URL",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 2430,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 0,
            "receivedBytes": 0,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596777594968
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
```

Any clue how to push the above payload, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Time Series Insights Gen2 data access concepts to push JSON content to Azure Time Series Insights.

Please refer [Azure Time Series Insights Gen2 data access concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response ashok, but I am seeing three options available for Gen2(Time Series Hierarchies,Time Series Instances,Time Series Types). For my above case I don't find any of the three fitting. Is there any vanilla case, like I can upload any json content bypassing the schema or I can restructure the schema according to my choice? All the Json content will be tagged with the time stamp